# why does clojure's map println only works in repl?

Tags: clojure

I use `lein new app test-println` to create a clojure app and launch the repl with `lein repl`, then I enter `(map println [1 2 3 4 5 6])` and get the expected result:

`test-println.core=> (map println [1 2 3 4 5 6])
1
2
3
4
5
6
(nil nil nil nil nil nil)`

However if I add `(map println [1 2 3 4 5 6])` to the end of `src/test_println/core.clj`:

```
(ns test-println.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!")
  (map println [1 2 3 4 5 6]))
```

`lean run` prints only `Hello, World!`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) is lazy. To quote the first sentence of the documentation (emphasis added):

> Returns a **lazy sequence** consisting of the result of applying f to the
>   set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set of
>   second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is exhausted.

The REPL forces evaluation of the expression to show the result, but nothing in your code does. [dorun](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun) would solve this, but you probably should look at [doseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) / [doall](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall) instead.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to run a single procedure over every item in a single collection, you should use [`run!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!):

```
(run! println [1 2 3 4 5 6])
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;; 4
;; 5
;; 6
;;=> nil
```

In cases where the action you need to perform on each collection is more complex than simply applying an existing function, [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) may be more convenient, but `run!` is a better choice here.